# Add class to HTML element when is dragged over another element in IE8

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I need to add class to one element when is dragged over another element. In HTML5 I do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/NeAUT

```
var draggedDiv = document.querySelector('.draggedDiv');
draggedDiv.draggable = true;

var draggedOver = document.querySelector('.draggedOver');
draggedOver.ondragover = function(){this.className = 'red'}
```

but I don't know how to do it to work in IE8.

Comment: Works for me when I turn the result pane of the fiddle into a XHTML document. What problems do you run into?

Comment: it's not valid for XHTML isn't it? And I need it to work even in IE8.

Comment: Sorry, what is not valid for XHTML? Anyway, if you need it to work in IE8, there's no reason to make it XHTML. IE8 doesn't do XHTML.

Comment: I mean Drag&Drop is not valid in XHTML if I'm not misinformed.

Comment: You mean the `draggable` attribute? Well, [this W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#the-draggable-attribute), which is subtitled "A vocabulary and associated APIs for HTML and XHTML", doesn't mention any restrictions for the `draggable` attribute...

Comment: Great but it doesn't solve my problem anyway. I need it to work in IE8 and Drag&Drop is not supported in IE8 so is it possible to write it different way (plugin, library etc.)?

Comment: Then that is what you should have asked: does anybody know of a way to do this in IE8. In other words, the question isn't about XHTML at all.

Comment: You're right. I will edit post and try to specify it better.